# How can I make a DataGridView refresh the entire row when a CheckBoxCell is clicked?

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, refresh

I have a DataGridView which is databound to a list of objects of one of my own classes. The DataGridView is set to display a text column and also two checkbox columns that behave like radio buttons: Clicking on an unchecked one checks it and unchecks the other, while clicking on a checked one does nothing.

I use a class like the following one to do this:

```
public class YesNoQuestion
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; }

    public bool Yes
    {
        get { return Value; }
        set
        {
            // This is supposed to work like a radio button, can't be unset.
            if (value)
            {
                Value = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool No
    {
        get { return !Value; }
        set
        {
            // This is supposed to work like a radio button, can't be unset.
            if (value)
            {
                Value = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Behind the scenes, this works as expected: Setting "Yes" to true sets "Value" to true which sets "No" to false and vice versa, but you can't set either "Yes" or "No" to false.

The problem is that the DataGridView row isn't updated until the row is unfocused, which means that (for example) unchecking "Yes" works while the underlying property is still "true" and checking "No" doesn't uncheck "Yes" while the underlying property has changed to false.

If I leave the row, the data appears correct. What I'd like to do is make sure that whenever either checkbox is clicked, the entire row's data is reloaded immediately.

How can that be done?

I tried to add the following, after a suggestion on a question about updating the *current* cell's value:

```
private void dgvQuestions_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvCheckValues.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        dgvCheckValues.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```

This works for the current cell's value, so you can't uncheck a box, but the other cell still remains checked. I tried to add `dgvCheckValues.InvalidateRow(dgvCheckValues.CurrentRow.Index);` but it has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in the end. It's because I was using a `List` instead of `BindingList`.

Alternatively, use a `BindingSource` as the DGV's datasource and set the `List` as the `BindingSource`'s source.

Comment: I thought the question was worth keeping even if I already found the answer, but I'll leave it to the moderators to decide if it should be deleted.